# Dictionary type params in query string

Tags: python-requests

I'm trying to feed the following URL structure into requests:

```
https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&filters={"City":"Las Vegas","State":"NV"}
```

I wanted to break up the URL into params, but am having a terrible time getting the filters portion to work properly. I ended up using the below code:

```
url = 'https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?' \
        'resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&' \
        'filters={"City":"' + city + '","State":"' + state + '"}'

resp = requests.get(url=url)
print resp.url
```

Does anybody know how I can modify this to work with requests like `requests.get(url=url, params=params)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like JSON data. You can convert a Python object to a JSON string with the [json module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json
import requests

city = 'Las Vegas'
state = 'NV'

filters = {
    'City': city,
    'State': state
}
params = {
    'resource_id': '8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b',
    'filters': json.dumps(filters)
}

response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/', params=params)
```

This sends a request to:

```
http://www.example.com/?filters=%7B%22City%22%3A+%22Las+Vegas%22%2C+%22State%22%3A+%22NV%22%7D&resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b
```

where

```
%7B%22City%22%3A+%22Las+Vegas%22%2C+%22State%22%3A+%22NV%22%7D
```

is the [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) version of

```
{"City": "Las Vegas", "State": "NV"}
```